# Loading Local Json file in React Application

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am trying to understand ho json files can be imported in react.

If I do

```
import jsonData from "./file.json";
console.log(jsonData[60]);
```

Why does this print out `explore`?

Does import automatically convert the json to an js obj since we don't have to parse it?

And why does doing a fetch call to an API which gives a JSON need to be parsed into a js obj?

What is the difference b/w the two methods that both give a json?

My file.json looks like

```
{
  "60" : {
    "action": "explore",
    "confd": "0.998647"
  },
  "120": {
    "action": "explore",
    "confd": "0.998647"
  },
  "180": {
    "action": "explore",
    "confd": "0.998647"
  }
}
```

Comment: A JSON file IS a JS object. That's literally what JSON stands for, so there's no "converting". If you just print the `jsonData` you should be able to see it's shape and contents. Not sure why you get that output, but check data shape

Answer (score 0):

- Create a .js file and then put your JSON data in it.
- Then Export it.

```
    export const myjson = {
        "60" : {
          "action": "explore",
          "confd": "0.998647"
        },
        "120": {
          "action": "explore",
          "confd": "0.998647"
        },
        "180": {
          "action": "explore",
          "confd": "0.998647"
        }
      };
```

- Import your JSON data from where you want to reach it.

```
    import { myjson } from "./jsonData.js";
```

Comment: but when I do a simple import of a json file, it behaves like an obj and doesn't parsing. Whereas the result from a fetch call (JSON ) needs to be parsed into a js obj before it is used

Comment: did you try jsonData.json();
for example;
var myJson = jsonData.json();

then work with myJson variable?

Comment: or if you want to see all jsonData and if it shows you as a object try this; JSON.stringify(jsonData);

Comment: i think he want to know behavior using .json file and result json from fetch, not how to use js object notation from file js

Comment: @RapSherlock that is correct. Because importing a local json file works as a js Obj. But a data from a fetch call has to converted using JSON.parse before it is used.